# Unit tests and SQLite in memory

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

The situation is as follows:

There are two databases from which in the application code samples are made and in these samples there are tables with the same name.

For unit tests, a test database (postgresql) was created with two schemas that embody the corresponding databases. Therefore, the problem with tables that have the same name has been resolved.

But, eventually, as the tests are written, they start to work more confidently more slowly. There is an idea to transfer the test DB to SQLite In-memory, but how in this case to solve a problem with the same name of tables?

Comment: You can create two sqlite-databases in memory at the same time?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, i'm not sure. I try to do this, but get the some error...

Comment: _"I get some error"_ isn't that helpful. Please share the error you're getting.

Comment: I'm curious as to what is causing the slowness with PostgreSQL in the first place; in my experience, the actual connection phase is often the slowest part (as opposed to the queries themselves), and using a connection pool such as pgbouncer ( https://pgbouncer.github.io/ ) can help there.